# What is the distribution of $X\vert Y$ where $Y$ is Bernoulli R.V?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> On good days customers arrive at an infinite server queue
>   according to a Poission process with rate $12$ per hour, whereas on other days
>   they arrive according to a Poisson process with rate $4$ per hour. The service times,
>   on all days, are exponentially distributed with rate $1$ per hour. Every day at time $10$
>   hours the system is shut down and all those presently in service are forced to leave
>   without completing service. Suppose that each day is, independently, a good day
>   with probability $0.5$ and that we want to use simulation to estimate $\theta$, the mean
>   number of customers per day that do not have their services completed.

My question regards only in finding $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ where $X$ denotes the number of costumers that do not have their services completed on any day and $Y$ denotes whether the day is good or ordinary. Therefore $Y$ is Bernoulli. (The hint given is that $X|Y$ follows a Poisson).

I was not able to find an explicit form for the distribution of $X$ given $Y$, but my reasoning in finding an approximate value of such goes as follows:

The average number of people that arrive per hour on a good day is $12$ and they stay in the system approximately $1$ hour each. On average $108$ people visit the server. Suppose now that we allow people in the server at time $10$, as soon as they walk in the server closes. But the average of people that walk is at $t=10$ is $12$, therefore 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X|Y=0\right]\approx12$$
and by the same reasoning
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X|Y=1\right]\approx4$$
where $Y=0$ denotes that the day is gonna be good with probability $1/2$ and $Y=1$ denotes that it is going to be bad with probability $1/2$.
My question is, how would I find the exact value of such expectations? Is it possible without any prior knowledge of stochastic processes?

---

**UDATE:**

After some research I found that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X\vert Y=0\right]=12\left(1-e^{-10}\right)$$
and

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X\vert Y=1\right]=4\left(1-e^{-10}\right)$$
Which indeed agrees with my approximation. I am wondering how this answers was derived, as the source I found it on does not give any motivation.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I will have to come back to it later. In the mean time, have you tried simulation?

Comment: Yes, I did the simulation.

Comment: @antkam I do not think that is right, suppose it is a good day, the average amount of people that get served before closing is $108$ because it takes $1$ hour to serve them. I am assuming that you are allowed to let people in the system, therefore the other $12$ come at $t=10$ and thus don't get their services completed (note there is no waiting time between the costumers). So $\mathbb{E}\left[X\vert Y=\text{good}\right]\approx 12$. In other words, the average amount of people that do not get their services completed by closing time ($=10$) on a good day is approximately $12$.

Comment: ah, sorry!  i had misread / misinterpreted "infinite server queue" to mean "single server, with infinite queue".  in fact it means $M/M/\infty$ i.e. infinite no. of servers.  my bad.

Comment: Does the system come back up after being shut down or does it stay shut down for the rest of the day?

Comment: I would assume it stays shut

Comment: From the question itself, it seemed to me the customers arrive at continuous times, but your interpretation seemed to indicate customers only arrive at whole hours (i.e. t=1, 2, 3, 4, ... instead of any float $t < 10$). Which one is true?

Comment: @XiaohaiZhang they do arrive continuous in time I’m using a heuristic argument to given an approximate answer to what the expectation is. But the number of arrivals is a poisson process with rate 12 per hour... it is more intuitive do consider t as taking on only integer values. Of course, that is why I refer to it as an approximation rather than an exact answer, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: And that is why I constantly use the term “on average”. My argument was not supposed to be rigorous but served the only purpose to give an estimation of what it could be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical textbook exercise on Poisson process.

Denote $N(t)$ be the total number of customers arrived before time $t$. From the given information, conditional on $Y = y$, $N(t)$ is just an ordinary Poission process, i.e. $N(t)|Y = y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_y t), y = 0, 1$.

Denote $W_n$ be the arrival time and $V_n$ be the corresponding service time of the $n$th customer. It is well known that $W_n|Y = y$ has a Gamma / Erlang distribution. $V_n$ is given to have an exponential distribution.

Note that the $n$th customer is having service at time $t$ if and only if $W_n < t$ (arrive before time $t$) and $W_n + V_n > t$ (leave after time $t$). $X$ can be viewed as the total number of customer having service at time $t$, and thus can be decomposed as a sum of indicators as follow:

$$ X = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}\{W_k < t, W_k + V_k > t\} \tag{*}$$

Consider
$$
\begin{align*}
&E[X|Y = y] \\
&= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}\{W_k < t, W_k + V_k > t\}
\Bigg|Y = y\right] \tag{1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} 
\mathbf{1}\{W_k < t, W_k + V_k > t\} \Bigg|N(t) = n, Y = y\right]\Pr\{N(t) = n|Y = y\} \tag{2}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n} 
\mathbf{1}\{W_k + V_k > t\} \Bigg|N(t) = n, Y = y\right]
e^{-\lambda_y t} \frac {(\lambda_y t)^n} {n!} \tag{3} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n} 
\mathbf{1}\{U_{(k)} + V_k > t\} \right]
e^{-\lambda_y t} \frac {(\lambda_y t)^n} {n!} \tag{4}  \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda_y t} \frac {(\lambda_y t)^n} {n!} 
 \sum_{k=1}^{n}  E\left[\mathbf{1}\{U_{k} + V_k > t\} \right] \tag{5} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda_y t} \frac {(\lambda_y t)^n} {n!} n\Pr\{U_1 + V_1 > t\}  \tag{6} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda_y t} \frac {(\lambda_y t)^n} {(n-1)!}
\int_0^t \frac {1} {t} \Pr\{V_1 > t - u\}du  \tag{7} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda_y t} \frac {\lambda_y^n t^{n-1}} {(n-1)!}
\int_0^t e^{-(t-u)}du  \tag{8} \\
&= \lambda_y \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda_y t} \frac {\lambda_y^n t^n} {n!}
(1 - e^{-t})  \tag{9} \\
&= \lambda_y(1 - e^{-t}) \tag{10}
\end{align*}
$$

where

$(1)$ is from the decomposition $(*)$

$(2)$ is law of total probability

$(3)$ we can drop the $N(t) = 0$ case in which $X = 0$; And $N(t) = n$ if and only if $W_1, W_2, \ldots, W_n \leq t$ and $W_{n+1}, W_{n+2}, \ldots > t$. so the sum inside the expectation is simplified. The last part is just Poisson pmf

$(4)$ is a crucial step: Conditional on $N(t) = n$, $W_k$ has an ordered uniform distribution on $(0, t)$, and denote by $U_{(k)}$, and it is independent of the rate $\lambda_y$

$(5)$ is another crucial step: Since the summand is a symmetric functional of those ordered statistics, it has the identical distribution with the unordered, original one, i.e. $U_k \sim \text{Uniform}(0, t)$

$(6)$ is due to the identical distribution of those $U_k + V_k$, and the expectation of indicator is just a probability

$(7)$ is a continuous version of law of total probability

$(8)$ is from the exponential CDF

$(9)$ is shifting index and computing the integral

$(10)$ is just summing the pmf to get 1